# restarting rake resques:scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, resque

I am using resque and resque-scheduler to schedule jobs in rails 3, any way I am building an interface for the user to change the values in the cron tab file but they don't reflect in the scheduler so I have to stop the `rake resque:scheduler` and then start it again is there a way to avoid this or programmatically restart the rake

Comment: i tried resque scheduler before. although it worked out fine, the whenever gem just feels more comfy. perhaps its for you, especially if  you want users to change the crontab

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Resque::Scheduler.dynamic` is set to `true` for your resque:scheduler rake task (and resque-web if you want it to be updated in the UI as well).

Comment: can you tell me where to put this line
I have two files
resque.rb in intializers

require 'resque_scheduler'
Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml")
-------------------------
and resque.rake

require "resque/tasks"
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'
task "resque:setup" => :environment